# The set of all segments is convex

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

If $X,Y\subset \mathbb R^n$ are convex sets, is it true the union of all segments $[x,y]$, where $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$ is a convex set?

I've drawn pictures and I convinced myself that this is true, but I couldn't formalize it, I need a hint or something how to proceed.

Thanks in advance

**My attempt of solution**

Using the answers below, this is my try:

We need to show that $r$ is in some segment $[x,y]$, where $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$. Note that:

$a=\lambda_1x_a+\lambda_2y_a$

$b=\lambda_1'x_b+\lambda_2'y_b$

$r=\lambda_1''a+\lambda_2''b$

Where

$\lambda_1+\lambda_2=1$

$\lambda_1'+\lambda_2'=1$

$\lambda_1''+\lambda_2''=1$

Rewriting $r$ we have:

$r=\lambda_1''a+\lambda_2''b=\lambda_1''(\lambda_1x_a+\lambda_2y_a)+\lambda_2''(\lambda_1'x_b+\lambda_2'y_b)=(\lambda_1''\lambda_1)x_a+(\lambda_1''\lambda_2)y_a+(\lambda_2''\lambda_1')x_b+(\lambda_2''\lambda_2')y_b$

Define:

$l_1=\lambda_1''\lambda_1$

$l_2=\lambda_1''\lambda_2$

$l_3=\lambda_2''\lambda_1'$

$l_4=\lambda_2''\lambda_2'$

Thus, we have:

$r=l_1x_a+l_2y_a+l_3x_b+l_4y_b$, where $l_1+l_2+l_3+l_4=1$

Then $r$ is a convex combination of $x_1,y_a,x_b,y_b$.

I can't see how to finish the solution.

Comment: Start from the definition of a convex set.

Comment: @YvesDaoust it was the first thing I did.

Comment: So what are the common elements between the definition and the question ?

Answer (score 4):

You are very close: You found
$$r=l_1 x_a+l_2y_a+l_3x_b+l_4y_b,\qquad l_1+l_2+l_3+l_4=1\ .$$
Now we have to produce a point $x_*\in X$ and a point $y_*\in Y$ such that $r\in[x_*,y_*]$. It's not farfetched to choose $x_*$ on the segment $[x_a,x_b]$; in fact, we could try
$$x_*:={l_1\over l_1+l_3}x_a+{l_3\over l_1+l_3}x_b\ ,$$
and similarly for $y_*$. Then $r=(l_1+l_3)x_*+(l_2+l_4)y_*$.

If one of the above denominators  $l_1+l_3$, $\>l_2+l_4$ is zero it is easily seen that $r\in Y$ or $r\in X$ to begin with.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's exactly what I was looking for!!!

Answer (score 1):

Lets define
$$Z := \bigcup_{x\in X,y\in Y} [x,y]$$
And take $a,b \in Z,\lambda \in (0,1)$. Then $\exists x_a,x_b \in X,y_a,y_b\in Y, \mu_a,\mu_b \in [0,1]$ such that
$$ a = \mu_a x_a + (1-\mu_a) y_a$$
$$ b = \mu_b x_b + (1-\mu_b) y_b$$

And we have
$$\lambda a + (1-\lambda) b = \lambda \mu_a x_a + (1-\lambda) \mu_b x_b + \lambda (1-\mu_a) y_a + (1-\lambda) (1-\mu_b) y_b$$

if we define 
$$\lambda_1 := \lambda \mu_a+ (1-\lambda) \mu_b$$
$$\lambda_2 := \lambda (1-\mu_a) + (1-\lambda) (1-\mu_b)$$

we notice that $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 = 1$. I'm gonna do the case when at least one of the $\mu_a,\mu_b$ is $>0$ and at least one is $<1$ (The other cases are simple). Whit this, $\lambda_1,\lambda_2>0$
$$\lambda a + (1-\lambda) b = \lambda_1 \left ( \frac{ \lambda \mu_a}{\lambda_1} x_a + \frac{(1-\lambda) \mu_b}{\lambda_1} x_b \right ) + \lambda_2 \left ( \frac{ \lambda (1-\mu_a)}{\lambda_2} y_a + \frac{(1-\lambda) (1-\mu_b)}{\lambda_2} y_b \right )$$
By convexity of $X$ and $Y$
$$ \bar x := \frac{ \lambda \mu_a}{\lambda_1} x_a + \frac{(1-\lambda) \mu_b}{\lambda_1} x_b \in X $$
$$\bar y := \frac{ \lambda (1-\mu_a)}{\lambda_2} y_a + \frac{(1-\lambda) (1-\mu_b)}{\lambda_2} y_b \in Y$$
and 
$$\lambda a + (1-\lambda) b = \lambda_1 \bar x + \lambda_2 \bar y\in [\bar x,\bar y] \subset Z$$

Comment: What's your strategy to solve this question? I mean, what's your intuitive idea to get these $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $Z$ be the defined set (union of all segments from $X$ to $Y$).

Let us choose two points from this set, let $p$ and $q$. By definition of $Z$, both belong to a line segment from $X$ to $Y$, let $x_py_p$ and $x_qy_q$.

We need to show that $pq$ is included in $Z$.

Indeed, let $r$ a point of $pq$. It is a convex combination of $p$ and $q$, themselves convex combinations of $x_p,y_p$ and $x_q,y_q$ respectively.

By distributivity, we can rewrite this combination as the combination of a combination of $x_p,x_q$ and a combination of $y_p,y_q$. Hence $r$ lies on a segment from $X$ to $Y$ and is in $Z$.

Comment: I proved that $r$ is a convex combination of $x_q,x_p,y_p,y_q$, but I couldn't finish the proof.

Comment: Can you see my edit, please?

Comment: The critical step is to turn the combination of combinations $((x_p,y_p),(x_q,y_q))$ into a combination of combinations $((x_p,x_q),(y_p,y_q))$. (I guess this is exactly what themaker managed.)

Comment: The critical step is to turn the combination of combinations $((x_p,y_p),(x_q,y_q))$ into a combination of combinations $((x_p,x_q),(y_p,y_q))$. You can do it by expressing the combinations in the form $ax_p+a^*y_p$, where $a^*=1-a$, expand the two combinations of combinations and solve for the new combination coefficients (you will get a compatible system of four equations in three unknowns)